# Need to Resolve Cursor positioned with Extra space comparing with Entry line for Material Entry in Xamarin.Forms for Ios devices

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, material-design, mobile-application

[image: image for cursor position with Extra space comparing entryline]

Currently in the above picture, there is some extra space before the Material Entry Text as well as the Placeholder comparing with Material Entry Line.I know there is an option of use customrenderers and i acheived the expected output in android.But it is not resolved in ios.Is there any solution for  remove the Extra space before the text and placeholder comparing with Material Entry Line for Ios.

Comment: Material Entry in iOS had set some style default which we could not customize it any more . It only can been implemented in default entry  .